# How to get nodes matching multiple tags with specific value on Overpass QL

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

I'm trying to fetch POI's that matched with tourism=museum or historic=memorial from Overpass API. 
I tried different queries but cannot find right solution, i'm getting empty response.

Here are not working queries

```
area["name"="Bursa"];                                                                     
(node["tourism"="museum"](area);); 
(node["historic"="memorial"](area););
out center;
```

```
area["name"="Bursa"];                                                               
(node["tourism"="museum"]|["historic"="memorial"](area);); 
out center;
```

I tried theese queries on [OverpassTurbo](https://overpass-turbo.eu/)

Thanks, Ersin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use a *named set* when performing multiple queries on the same area (which is also just a set). Otherwise the second query will be performed on the result of the first query.

```
area["name"="Bursa"]->.a;
(
  node["tourism"="museum"](area.a);
  node["historic"="memorial"](area.a);
);
out center;
```

Also note that you are just querying for [nodes](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nodes), so your query won't find any museums or memorials added as [way](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Ways) or [relation](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Relation). The following query will include those, too:

```
area["name"="Bursa"]->.a;
(
  nwr["tourism"="museum"](area.a);
  nwr["historic"="memorial"](area.a);
);
out center;
```

Comment: that's exactly what i looking for and it's works like a charm.Thank you so much @scai

Comment: @scai any chance you know how to make this query work with coordinates? I have a similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61025327/find-multiple-tags-around-coordinates-with-overpass-api. Thanks