# Find multiple tags around coordinates with Overpass API

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

Given this overpass query https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/Sle, that searches for museums and galleries, how can I introduce a new type of tag to search around the same location, for example I want to also search for `node["amenity"~"cafe|bar"]` around the same area (500 meters around `lat: 500,53.866444` and `lon: 10.684738`. Everything I've tried either raises an error or returns incomplete results. For example, the following works, but only returns cafés and bars but no museums.

```
[out:json];
  node["tourism"~"museum|gallery"](around:500,53.866444, 10.684738);
  node["amenity"~"cafe|bar"](around:500,53.866444, 10.684738);
  out center;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to combine both result sets:

```
[out:json];
(
  node["tourism"~"museum|gallery"](around:500,53.866444, 10.684738);
  node["amenity"~"cafe|bar"](around:500,53.866444, 10.684738);
);
out center;
```

See https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/Ss6.

Alternatively try using the wizard at overpass-turbo, for example by searching for `tourism~"museum|gallery" or amenity~"cafe|bar"`.

Also note that you are just searching for [nodes](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Node). You will miss POIs mapped as [ways](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Way) or [relations](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Relation) (the latter occurs rarely, though). So either add additional queries for ways and relations or replace `node` with `nwr` (node way relation).