# Why does 'around' work but 'area' doesn't in Overpass Turbo?

Tags: geolocation, maps, openstreetmap, overpass-api

I have the following overpass turbo query:

```
[out:json];
area[name="Zagreb"];
(
  node["tourism"~"museum|gallery"](area);
  node["amenity"~"cafe|bar"](area);
);
out center;
```

You can run it here: https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/1hmp

The problem is that it only returns the first node, so the tourism="museum|gallery" in this case, but not the amenity="cafe|bar".

I based my query on this answer, where both nodes get returned(!!!): [Find multiple tags around coordinates with Overpass API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61025327/find-multiple-tags-around-coordinates-with-overpass-api)

```
[out:json];
(
  node["tourism"~"museum|gallery"](around:500,53.866444, 10.684738);
  node["amenity"~"cafe|bar"](around:500,53.866444, 10.684738);
);
out center;
```

You can run this original one here: https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/1hml

Except that I changed the 'around' to the area of name="Zagreb". And this clearly works (although just for one of the nodes).

Does anyone have any ideas how to get both nodes (tourism="museum|gallery" and amenity="cafe|bar") to work within an area?

Thanks so much!
Lovro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store the area in a named inputset (below it's named ".myarea"), otherwise the result of the first node statement would overwrite the area in the default inputset (called ._), and would no longer be available for the second node query.

```
[out:json];
area[name="Zagreb"]->.myarea;
(
  node["tourism"~"museum|gallery"](area.myarea);
  node["amenity"~"cafe|bar"](area.myarea);
);
out center;
```

Quite a frequent issue by the way, and I'm sure there are several other post that already deal with this error.

Comment: Huh, interesting. I never would have thought about something like this, and unfortunately I didn't stumble upon it in my research.

Thanks so much for your time and effort, I appreciate it! :)